# How to install Citrix receiver?

Tags: installation, citrix

How can I install Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu, Please try and edit your question giving us more information about your system. RAM, Processor, and any further information which may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Citrix Receiver requires OpenMotif v2.3.1 or greater to use the Graphical User Interface.

The first step is to install OpenMotif 2.3.1.  You can download OpenMotif from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/openmotif).  Once downloaded and installed, download [Citrix Receiver](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-121.html). deb file.

Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded (probably the Downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

For more info visit [Citrix](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125285)

**Edit**

If you get the eeror below installing the 64bit

```
dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: icaclient
```

Try this:

1. Install the .deb and let it fail
2. Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/icaclient.postinst`
3. Replace the line that says `echo $Arch|grep "i[0-9]86&quot; >/dev/null` with `*echo $Arch|grep -E "i[0-9]86|x86_64" >/dev/null` (note the -E after grep!)
4. Run `sudo dpkg --configure icaclient`

<sup>Source for Edit:[Citrix Forums](http://forums.citrix.com/forum.jspa?forumID=1406&start=0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks i already tried it and encountered the below error


root@shadow:/home/sid/Desktop# sudo dpkg -i icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 268102 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace icaclient 12.1.0 (using icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement icaclient ...
Setting up icaclient (12.1.0) ...
dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient

Answer (score 0):

A little update 3 years later:
Download the .deb file from Citrix and click open. Proceed as usual from there:

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-latest.html